# C++ how to delete list element by user input

Tags: c++

In a program after an array is created, user can choose and delete one element from the array.
After that, the program will show the array without this element.

A requirement for this homework is using pointers.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *x = NULL;
    int n;
    int cyfry;

    cout << "podaj dlugosc listy\n"; // array lenght
    cin >> n;

    x = new int[n];
    cout << "podaj cyfry do listy\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> cyfry;
        x[i] = cyfry;  // input values to array
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // values in array
        cout << x[i] << ",";
}
```

Comment: That is not an array. That is a pointer to an object of `n` ints.

Comment: Allocate new memory of one less element. Copy all but the unwanted element to the new memory. Free the old memory. Make `x` point to the new memory. Done.

Comment: Could You show me how to do that ?

Comment: Yes he can, but he should not have to. Take a stab at implementing it yourself and if what you produce does not work, we will help you fix it.

Comment: I'm totally stack with this and I have no idea how start with this. That's the problem.

Comment: You want to delete an specific element, or the element of an specific position of the array?

Comment: To delete one of the element by user input, position in array is irrelevant.

Comment: remember when you answer someone's comment in comment section, add "@nameOfUser" so they can get the notification!

Comment: @M.K thank you for advice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude gave you the answer 4 hours ago. You can't delete part of an array. You can only delete the whole thing. So if you really want to free the 1 element you have do allocate a new array of n-1 elements, copy then delete the original. An alternate solution is to just shift all elements past the one to delete 1 position to the left. Just remember that there are now n-1 valid elements in the array. A smart solution would remember many elements were allocated in the array with a capacity variable. This is similar to how  a std::vector works.

Comment: FYI in modern c++ code you would not work with `new` or `delete` anymore. Either allocate the element on the stack, or use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` if you need to allocate on heap. And for container you use the `std` containers like `std::array`, `std::vector`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
int main()

    int* wskaznik = NULL;
    int ile;
    int cyfry;

    cout << "podaj dlugosc listy\n";
    cin >> ile;

    wskaznik = new int[ile];
    cout << "podaj cyfry do listy\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < ile; i++) {
        cin >> cyfry;
        wskaznik[i] = cyfry;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ile; i++)
        cout << wskaznik[i] << ",";

    int* n_wskaznik = new int[ile - 1];

    int usun;
    / int j = 0;
    cin >> usun;

    int znajdz = 0; // potrzebny mechanizm wybierający tylko pierwszy element

    for (int i = 0; i < ile; i++) {
        if (usun != wskaznik[i]) // '==' pokarze wybrane,  '!+' usunie wybrane
        {

            n_wskaznik[j] = wskaznik[i];
            j++;
            cout << wskaznik[i] << ",";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `std::swap()` instead of the part with `Temp`. Although I assume in class you are limited to what parts of the standard library that you are permitted to use.

Comment: After the shift just decrease `dlugoscListy` by 1 instead of having to use `dlugoscListy -1`. Think about what happens if you are asked to remove a second item in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the case that you want to delete one element of the array that the user inputs. 
It is not a perfect solution as the newArray has only 1 less element, and in the for you delete all of them. But it is for as you get the idea on how to do it! You have not tried a single thing (at least by what you have showed us).

Have this summmed up to the code you already have:

```
     newArray = new int[n-1];
        int toDelete;
        cin>>toDelete;
        int j=0;


       /*this deletes ALL elements that are, for example, "2" of the array of ints.
     If you want to delete only the first found, 
you can use a boolean (or a int found=0;), 
and in the if case, use this found*/

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(toDelete!=x[i]){
            /*we use "j" because newArray has 1 less element than x. So we will be adding numbers
            in case the element is the one we want to delete, we do not add it, so j does not sum up. */
                newArray[j]=x[i];
                j++;
            }

        }
```

Implement this in your code, in the `for`loop, and do what you have to do with the code! I hope this example solved your doubts!

EDIT: In the case (as asked several hours ago from months ago of the question), in the case you only want to delete the first encounter of an element: f.e:

`[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]` and element to delete is 2, the final array: `[1,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int size=9;
        int* firstArray=new int[size];
        //just an example to add up the array. This is quite dirty, but as to see the easy example
        firstArray[0]=1;
        firstArray[1]=2;
        firstArray[2]=3;
        firstArray[3]=1;
        firstArray[4]=2;
        firstArray[5]=3;
        firstArray[6]=1;
        firstArray[7]=2;
        firstArray[8]=3;
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            cout<<firstArray[i];
        cout<<endl;
        int* newArray = new int[size-1];
        int toDelete;
        cin>>toDelete;
        int j=0;
        bool counter=false; //this counter will tell us if we have deleted it once
        //[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            //if the element we want to delete, is not in the array
            if(toDelete!=firstArray[i]){
                newArray[j]=firstArray[i];
                j++;
            }
            //if we find the element to delete and we have not deleted it yet, we dont copy it
            else if (toDelete==firstArray[i] && counter==false) {
                counter=true;
            }
            //if we have already deleted it, nothing. 
             else if (toDelete==firstArray[i] && counter==true) {
                newArray[j]=firstArray[i];
                j++;

            }


        }
        for (int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
             cout<< newArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Hello. I back to this Code, white in that way you said. we discussed on another forum what if and bool I have to use to delete only first element and We can't do this without vectors. Can you show me . I put code on the bottom of the site

Comment: I do not understand your new question. Please explain it to me! You want to delete just the 1st element of the array? like `[3,2,5,4,7,1]` would be `[2,5,4,7,1]` ? @TomaszPawełNowicki

Comment: now if you input for example [3,2,4,2,2] and choose 2 to delete programs give [3,4] but we want to have [3,4,2,2]

Comment: I have edited it now. Please, if it suits you, also upvote the answer!  Any comments or doubts please ask! @TomaszPawełNowicki